# When I make a GET request to NodeJS it doesn't run the code in the route

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am trying to make a get request with ajax, it doesn't seem to run the code in my NodeJS /tools route, maybe someone can enlighten me. I am looking to run a script from nodeJS from an AJAX request. xhr GET request doesn't seem to work with to initiate the that console log in the nodejs route.

These are my routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user.js');
const mid = require('../middleware');
const axios = require('axios');
// Home Routes

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index');
});

// About Routes

router.get('/about', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('about', {title : '| About'});
});

// Tools Routes

router.get('/tools', (req, res, next) => { 
    console.log("ajax request went through!");

});

router.post('/tools', (req, res, next) => {
    var domain = req.body.domain;
    canYouDigIt(domain);

});

router.get('/map', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('map');
});
// Login Routes

router.get('/login', mid.loggedOut, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('login', {title : '| Log in'});
});

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    if ( req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function(error, user){
            if (error || !user) {
                var err =new Error('Wrong email or password.');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                return res.redirect('/profile');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var err =new Error('Email and password are required!');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }

});


// Logout Routes

router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session){
        // Delete Session
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    }
});

// Registration Routes 

router.get('/registration', mid.loggedOut, (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('registration', {title : '| Registration'});
});

router.post('/registration', (req, res, next) => {
    // Check if all fields are filled
    if (req.body.userName && req.body.password && req.body.confirmPassword && req.body.firstName && req.body.lastName && req.body.email) {

        // Confirm Password is the same
        if ( req.body.password != req.body.confirmPassword) {
            const err = new Error ("Passwords don't match!");
            err.status = 400;
            return next(err);
        };

        const userData = {
            userName: req.body.userName,
            password: req.body.password,
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email
        };

        // Use schema 'create' method to insert document into Mongo
        User.create(userData, (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            } else {
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                return res.redirect('/profile');
            }
        });
    } else {
        const err = new Error("All Fields Required.");
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

This is my html/pug calling the route

```
section(id="digToolWrapper")
        form( id="digToolInput" )
            ul
                li #[input(id="digTool" name="domain" type="text" placeholder="Can you dig it?")]#[input(id="whois" value="whois" type="button" onclick="digIt()")]
```

This is my ajax request

```
function digIt() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var domain = document.getElementById("digTool").value;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          console.log(domain);
        }
     };
    xhr.open('GET', '/tools', true);
    console.log(domain);
    xhr.send();

};
```

App.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();


// Mongodb connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/nymadic", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection
// Mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));


// Use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat!',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // This stores sessions in the Mongo DB so the server doesnt become overloaded
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db
    })
}));


// Make user ID available in template 
app.use(function (req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.session.userId;
    next();
});

// Body Parser and Cookie Parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Static Files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Pug Render Engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Routes
const mainRoutes = require('./routes');
const profileRoutes = require('./routes/profile');
const wikiRoutes = require('./routes/wiki');

app.use(mainRoutes);
app.use('/profile', profileRoutes);
app.use('/wiki', wikiRoutes);

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Nodejs is running on port 8080...');
  });
```

Comment: Did you start the server? I don't see the code to start the server in your nodeJS file...for e.g.,    app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log('listening on 3000');
    });

Comment: Sorry this is a route I can add the app.js file. The server would have to be running for me to even attempt this.

Comment: You can ignore the obtaining of the domain, that works fine. I just cant get the console log in my nodejs tools route to work. If I can get that to work everything else will work. The whois is just the button name.

Comment: Well is there anything in `request` in you routes? Does the request actually get sent to the server? Or just the `domain` property isn't available in the request?

Comment: I am just trying to console.log to make sure it is getting through or is there a specific thing I need to do in my /tools route.

Comment: can you try this directly in the browser and let me know the response....try http://<your server name>:<your port>/tools......also send back something in the response in your node js file...like res.send('Hi');

Comment: Okay, that worked it rendered hi in the viewport for /tools.

Comment: Ohh woah. It worked I add, it let me get the domain when i did my ajax request :
res.send("hi");
    next();